# I can't get value from select option to MySQL (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring

I've got problem with my project. (It is my first Spring project, sorry for messy code). I want to insert values from form to DB, (for that moment they are working inputs called "nameHosp", "namePat", "surnamePat","peselPat"). And the problem is passing value from select options form. Result of submiting is "null" in column called "nameHosp"

**Form**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        `<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    `
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


        <sf:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/create"
            method="post" modelAttribute="combinedCommand" >

            <table style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" width="100%">

                <tr><sf:form modelAttribute="combinedCommand">
                <td colspan="5"><strong>Szpital zamawiający</strong><br /> <br />
                    <sf:select path="${getHospitals}">
                        <sf:option value="NONE"> --Wybierz Szpital--</sf:option>
                        <sf:options items="${hospitals}"  itemValue="nameHosp" itemLabel="nameHosp"></sf:options>
                    </sf:select></sf:form>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Dane pacjenta</th>
                <th colspan="4">Zamówienie</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Imię:<br /> <sf:input path="${namePat}" name="namePat"
                        type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>KKCz</td>
                <td><input name="iloscKKCz" size="1" type="text" /> jednostek.
                </td>
                <td><input name="ED5" type="checkbox" value="86" />
                    Ubogoleukocytarny</td>
                <td><input name="EC2" type="checkbox" value="26" />
                    Napromieniowany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nazwisko:<br /> <sf:input path="${surnamePat}"
                        name="surnamePat" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>PLT</td>
                <td><input name="iloscPLT" size="1" type="text" /> jednostek.
                </td>
                <td><input name="ED5" type="checkbox" value="86" />
                    Ubogoleukocytarny</td>
                <td><input name="EC2" type="checkbox" value="26" />
                    Napromieniowany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PESEL:<br /> <sf:input path="${peselPat}" name="peselPat"
                        type="text" />

</table>
    </sf:form>
```

**Controller**

```
   @Controller
public class Controlling {
    @Autowired
    private Servicu servicu;
@Autowired
public void setServicu(Servicu servicu) {
    this.servicu = servicu;
}


@RequestMapping("/")
public String showHome(Model model) {

    return "home";
}
@RequestMapping("/orderForm")
public String showForm(Model model){
    List<Hospitals> hospital = servicu.getCurrent();
    model.addAttribute("combinedCommand", new CombinedCommand());
    model.addAttribute("hospitals", hospital);
    model.addAttribute("ordersPatient", new OrdersPatient());
    return "orderForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doCreate( Hospitals hospitals,
                Model model, 
                OrdersPatient ordersPatient, 
                Orders orders, 
                BindingResult result) {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "error";
    }else{




model.addAttribute("nameHosp",hospitals);   
//      model.addAttribute("combinedCommand", new CombinedCommand());
        model.addAttribute("ordersPatient", new OrdersPatient());
        servicu.create(ordersPatient);
//      servicu.create(orders);

        return "success";
}
```

**DAO**

```
  @Component("offersDAO")
public class OffersDAO {
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource jdbc) {
    this.jdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbc);
}

public List<Hospitals> getHosps() {

    return jdbc.query("select nameHosp from hospitals", new RowMapper<Hospitals>() {

        public Hospitals mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Hospitals hospital = new Hospitals("nameHosp");

            hospital.setNameHosp(rs.getString("nameHosp"));

            return hospital;
        }

    });
}

public boolean createPatient(OrdersPatient ordersPatient){
    BeanPropertySqlParameterSource param = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(ordersPatient);

    return jdbc.update("insert into patient (idOrd,nameHosp,namePat,surnamePat,peselPat) values (:idOrd,:nameHosp,:namePat,:surnamePat,:peselPat)", param)==1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `name="nameHosp"` to the select. Like this.

```
<sf:select path="${getHospitals}" name="nameHosp">
     <sf:option value="NONE"> --Wybierz Szpital--</sf:option>
     <sf:options items="${hospitals}"  itemValue="nameHosp" itemLabel="nameHosp"></sf:options>
</sf:select></sf:form>
```